# Order WordPress custom post types by ACF field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to order posts of custom post type 'listings' on an ACF TRUE / FALSE field ('premium'). Why doesn't this work?

```
// Pre get posts function
function pre_sort_filter_premium( $query ) { 
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
         if ( is_singular('listings') ) {
            $query->set('meta_key', 'premium');
            $query->set('orderby', array('meta_value' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC'));
        } 
    } 
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pre_sort_filter_premium' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You say your meta ACF field is a true or false field type. This field type would save the meta acf field value in the database as `0` or `1` integer.

Descending `DESC` order means all the posts where `premium` is set to true `1` will appear first.

So if you want order `listings` posts by `premium` meta field in `DESC` order then it would be something like this...

**Not tested but in theory orderby will order both meta value and date in descending order.**

```php
// pre get posts function
function pre_sort_filter_premium($query) { 
    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
         if(is_singular('listings')) {
            $query->set('meta_type', 'NUMERIC');
            $query->set('meta_key', 'premium');
            $query->set('orderby', array(
                'meta_value_num', 
                'date'
            );
            $query->set('order', 'DESC');
        } 
    } 
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'pre_sort_filter_premium');
```

Good luck hope this helps.